# Is it possible to use jQuery filter() with a specific checkbox state?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been playing around with Jquery to try and do something cool with bootstraps 4's input groups. The idea is, when a user checks the checkbox the input group housing that element would turn green.

I thought I would be able to use '.filter' helping me keep the code clean, but I'm not sure I'm getting it right. See my snippet below.

```
$('.form-checkbox').filter(function () {
  return ($(this).is(':checked'))
}).toggleClass("sub-green");
```

Here's my current attempt [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/eunzx0hg/7/). Any help I could get with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: And the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your logic. Firstly you need to change the class when the checked property of the checkbox changes. To do that execute your code in a `change` event handler.

Secondly you don't need `filter()`. You instead need to use `this` to affect the element which raised the event. Then you can provide the `checked` property to `toggleClass()` to add or remove the class as needed.

Finally you need to put the class on the parent `input-group-text` element, not the checkbox itself. To do that use `closest()`. Try this:

```
$('.form-checkbox').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.input-group-text').toggleClass("sub-green", this.checked);
});
```

```js
// Trigger collapse on enter key down
$("#newsletter-email").keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("div").find("#subscribe-collapse").trigger('click');
    return false;
  }
});

$(".btn-nl-collapse").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("sub-black");
});

// Checkbox Styling

$('.form-checkbox').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.input-group-text').toggleClass("sub-green", this.checked);
});
```

```css
* {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.bg-primary {
  background-color: #ededed !important;
}

.sec-spacer-xl {
  padding: 8rem;
}


/* == Additional Styles == */


/* ======================= */

.body-link-external::after {
  content: "\f08e";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.disclaimer {
  font-size: .7rem;
}


/* == form styles == */


/* ================= */

.form-hidden {
  display: none;
}

label {
  margin: 0;
}

.form-element {
  min-width: 280px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.form-element:focus {
  min-width: 280px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fefdf3;
  transition: ease all .2s;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: 0 none;
}

.btn-nl-collapse {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: ease all .3s;
}

.btn-nl-collapse:hover,
.btn-nl-collapse.sub-black {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.btn-nl-collapse:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: 0 none;
}

.form-element::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #777 !important;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.form-element:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #777 !important;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.form-element::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #777 !important;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.form-element:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #777 !important;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.form-element:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.form-element:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.form-element:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.form-element:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.check-input:disabled {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-group-text.sub-green {
  background-color: rgba(156, 195, 32, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid @9cc320;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css">
<section id="newsletter" class="sec-spacer-xl bg-primary">
  <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $container ); ?>">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
        <form>
          <label for="newsletter-email" class="form-hidden">Please enter your email address:</label>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-element" placeholder="john.smith@example.co.uk" aria-label="Email Address" aria-describedby="subscribe-collapse" id="newsletter-email">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-nl-collapse" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#gdpr-info-pane" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="gdpr-info-pane" id="subscribe-collapse"><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse" id="gdpr-info-pane">
            <div class="card card-body">
              <h5>Almost there, we just need to confirm a few extra details...</h5>
              <p>We use Mailchimp as our marketing platform and make use of thier tools to securely maintain and handle our subscribers data. Your data will never be shared with third parties and we will never send you spam. </p>
              <p>
                <strong>How you would like to hear from us?</strong>
              </p>
              <label class="checkbox subfield" for="gdpr_8861">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                      <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" id="gdpr_8861" name="gdpr[8861]" value="Y" class="av-checkbox form-checkbox">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control check-input" placeholder="Emails & Updates" aria-label="email-text" disabled>
                </div>
              </label>
              <label class="checkbox subfield" for="gdpr_8865">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                      <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" id="gdpr_8865" name="gdpr[8865]" value="Y" class="av-checkbox form-checkbox">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control check-input" placeholder="Direct Mail" aria-label="direct-mail-text" disabled>
                </div>
              </label>
              <label class="checkbox subfield" for="gdpr_8869">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">

                      <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" id="gdpr_8869" name="gdpr[8869]" value="Y" class="av-checkbox form-checkbox">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control check-input" placeholder="Online Advertising" aria-label="online-advertising-text" disabled>
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, could I use filter if I wanted to or would that be a bad choice?

Comment: Ultimately this a clean example, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the assist?

Comment: You could but it would be a bad choice in this scenario, as your current logic adds the class on the first click (to check the box) then leaves it on when the checkbox is clicked again, then removes it on the next click. You would need to change the logic around to several lines to check the current state and remove it as well, which this does all in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

First You need to execute :

```
$('.form-checkbox').filter(function () {
  return ($(this).is(':checked'))
}).toggleClass("sub-green");
```

when one of thoses `checkbox` is changed.

you can use `on('change')` event like :

```
$(".form-checkbox").on('change',function() {
  // example
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    // this OR target 
    $(this).addClass("sub-green");
  } else {
    // this OR target
    $(this).removeClass('sub-green');
  }
  // or
  $('.form-checkbox').filter(function () {
     return ($(this).is(':checked'))
  }).toggleClass("sub-green");
})
```